# Spark - write Avro file

Tags: apache-spark, avro

What are the common practices to write Avro files with Spark (using Scala API) in a flow like this:

1. parse some logs files from HDFS
2. for each log file apply some business logic and generate Avro file (or maybe merge multiple files)
3. write Avro files to HDFS

I tried to use spark-avro, but it doesn't help much.

```
val someLogs = sc.textFile(inputPath)

val rowRDD = someLogs.map { line =>
  createRow(...)
}

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
dataFrame.write.avro(outputPath)
```

This fails with error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
      Reference 'StringField' is ambiguous, could be: StringField#0, StringField#1, StringField#2, StringField#3, ...
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? For example why  ` spark-avro` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I did not succeed using Avro generated java code with spark-avro. Also when I am using the Schema API I get this kind of errors: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'StringField' is ambiguous, could be: StringField#0, StringField#1, StringField#2, StringField#3,

Comment: @d4rkang3l Are you sure that the problem is with avro serialization? Is dataFrame generated without problems?

Answer (score 15):

Databricks provided library spark-avro, which helps us in reading and writing Avro data.

```
dataframe.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Spark 2 and Scala 2.11**

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

// Do all your operations and save it on your Dataframe say (dataFrame)

dataFrame.write.avro("/tmp/output")
```

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: In Java 8:        df2.write().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(f.getOutputPath());

Comment: I doubt .avro("/tmp/output") works. I think this way should used: write.format("avro").save(/output/path)

Answer (score 2):

You need to start spark shell to include avro package..recommended for lower versions

> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0

Then use to df to write as avro file-

```
dataframe.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outputPath)
```

And write as avro table in hive -

```
dataframe.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").saveAsTable(hivedb.hivetable_avro)
```

Comment: Paul  The syntax for "append"  to table, I cannot seem to get it correct. Can you verify if possible and how please?

Comment: The '.saveAsTable(hivedb.hivetable_avro)' part will have problems with below warning: 
WARN hive.HiveExternalCatalog: Couldn't find corresponding Hive SerDe for data source provider com.databricks.spark.avro. Persisting data source table `dbName.Suchas.hivedb`.`tableName.suchas.hivetable_avro` into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive.

At least this was happening for spark2