# Port data from HDFS/S3 to local FS and load in Java

Tags: apache-spark-sql, avro, parquet, spark-avro, hive-serde

I have a Spark job running on an EMr cluster that writes out a DataFrame to HDFS (which is then `s3-dist-cp`-ed to `S3`). The data size isn't big (2 GB when saved as `parquet`). These data in S3 are then copied to a local filesystem (EC2 instance running Linux) and then loaded into a Java application.

It turns out I cannot have the data in `parquet` format because parquet has been designed for HDFS and cannot be used in local FS (if I am wrong, please point me to a resource on how to read parquet files on local FS).

What other format can I use to address this? Would Avro be compact enough and not blow up the size of data by packing the schema with each row of the dataframe?

Comment: Writing DF out as Avro worked without much avro schema overhead. Though `parquet` was better at creating smaller files but the blow up wasn't much (20%).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use Parquet on a local filesystem. To see an example in action, download the parquet-mr library from [here](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/releases/tag/apache-parquet-1.10.0), build it with the local profile (`mvn -P local install` should do it, provided that you have `thrift` and `protoc` installed), then issue the following to see the contents of your parquet file:

```
java -jar parquet-tools/target/parquet-tools-1.10.0.jar cat /path/to/your-file.parquet
```

Comment: Writing to Avro worked for me. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878433/spark-write-avro-file) SO post which helped me write DF out as Avro.